# Authenticating with Google Calendar API

Tags: java, android, google-api, google-api-java-client

I'm writing an Android app that uses both the Google Tasks and Calendar API. Authenticating through the Tasks works perfectly. But, when accessing the calendar API, I get a screen that says "A problem occurred while communicating with Google services. Please try again later." with the heading "Couldn't sign in". If I click next, a signing in... screen is displayed for about half a second, then I'm sent back to the "problem occurred" screen.

The code where I authenticate to the Calendar API is below. Note that the code for the Tasks API, which works fine, is almost identical.

```
GoogleAccountManager google_manager = new GoogleAccountManager(this);
Account[] accounts = google_manager.getAccounts();
Account my_account;
if (accounts.length > 1) my_account = selectWhichAccount(accounts);
else {
    if (accounts.length == 0) display_no_account_dialog();
    Log.v("account",accounts[0].toString());
    my_account = accounts[0];
}
final String AUTH_TOKEN_TYPE = "oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar";
Log.v("schedule","getting auth token");
google_manager.manager.getAuthToken(my_account, AUTH_TOKEN_TYPE, null, this, new AccountManagerCallback<Bundle>() {

        @Override
        public void run(AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> future) {
            try {
                String token = future.getResult().getString(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN);
                Log.d("schedule","starting scheduletask");
                start_ScheduleTask(t, token);
            } catch (OperationCanceledException e) {
                Log.v("accounts","denied access to account");
                handleException(e);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                handleException(e);
            }
        }
    }, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

OAuth2 tokens specified using the 'oauth2:' prefix are only partially supported by `AccountManager` and some of them don't work. Unfortunately, what is supported and what is not  is not currently documented (AFAIK). You have two alternatives: use ClientLogin (use 'cl' as the token type) or get a token using a WebView. The ClientLogin should work fine for now, however it is officially deprecated and will be going away in about a year.